# FDT's Haxe Viewer Won't Launch My Project

Tags: eclipse, haxe, launching-application, fdt

I tired to and set the Launch URI using the browse button, but it doesn't seem to be wired up. Also if I try and set a configured path relative to the project (bin/js/index-debug.html) it reports that "Please select a valid URI file".

[image]

Here is a sample of my .HXML file for more detail:

```
-main ClassCollector
-cp lib/collector
-neko bin/collector/ClassCollector.n
-cmd neko bin/collector/ClassCollector.n src/main/haxe examples/main/haxe/All.hx -class
```

Answer (score 0):

> -cmd neko bin/collector/ClassCollector.n src/main/haxe examples/main/haxe/All.hx -class

When using FDT for Haxe, you *currently* cannot run commands in the .HXML file. This will also cause other problems such as slow autocompletion and other errors.

This may change in a later version of FDT.